# Solving a linear program with (sub) gradient descent

Tags: algorithms, convex-optimization, linear-programming, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Can one solve a linear program with gradient descent?

Smoothness should not be a problem, because non-smooth ReLu units seem not to cause a problem for gradient descent solvers.

Constraints should be handleable with an augmented Lagrangian method.

Comment: Do you mean a level set method? If so that's one way.  But there might be better ways to handle LPs. If you only have equality constraints you can systematically eliminate them, then use gradient descent over the "solution subspace". If you are working with a smaller problem you can use interior point methods, or do gradient descent over a log barrier penalty.

Comment: Although machine learning people often say that the nondifferentiability of ReLu is not a problem for gradient descent, it's unclear to me to what extent this is really true. When training neural networks it's not necessary to solve the optimization problem very accurately, and in fact stopping the iteration early can be used as a form of "regularization". Maybe they don't even want to solve the optimization problem to high accuracy, because that might lead to overfitting. However, when solving LPs, usually we want an accurate solution, and in that case nondifferentiability could be a problem.

Comment: @littleO Well even mathematically,  a subgradient descent should be able to minimize the objective function. Are you concerned about the rate of convergence?  Once KKT conditions hold for a linear program, then we must be at global solution. Right? (I might be totally wrong)

Comment: @whyyes you typically cannot eliminate equality constraints due to nonnegativity constraints.

Comment: @whyyes No, I simply meant augmented Lagrangian.

Comment: @LinAlg Imposing constraints is possible in many method based on gradient descent.

Comment: @LinAlg good point; that only works if you only have equality constraints and no other constraints, and even then it can have undesired effects (removing sparsity, e.g.)

Comment: @user25004 so how do you deal with the dual variable?  If you remove the dual variable term you get a penalty function and that works if you diminish the step size, but then convergence could be slow. You can just use ADMM if you have the augmented  Lagrangian available though.

Comment: @littleO yeah it's kind of like subgradient descent but without a diminishing step size, or you do diminish via epochs until you get the validation error you want. But it's funny how many papers cite opposing "black magic" advice on the decay schedule; some even recommend increasing initially!

Comment: @whyyes Good points. Another issue is that when using ReLu I'm not aware of any chain rule for subgradients that guarantees that the vector we compute using backpropagation really is a subgradient of the objective function. The objective function is nonconvex so I think it might not even have a subgradient at many points. So, when people differentiate ReLu (blithely ignoring the nondifferentiability) I don't think we can even claim to be using subgradient descent. It seems like people just cross their fingers and hope for the best. (Of course, they often get great results.)